# how can I use the same template multiple times on meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, handlebars.js

I just started use meteor about a week ago, and I'm trying to write my first app for logging time for a project.

At the end of the day users can go in and log their hours with a single row consisting of 2 drop down select menus. First is the clients drop down. then based on that client (using Session) the 2nd drop down for client projects will auto-populate, and finally allowing you to enter your hours in a text input.

I have this working, but I also need to implement a button so you can add multiple rows at once. Sort of like jQuery Clone() in case the user worked on different clients or client projects.

I tried to re-render the row once newRow is clicked, but then the second row manipulates the first row because I'm assuming they're both referencing the same template.

To simplify? 1) How do I duplicate the  below the last one, and 2) How do I use the same template for 1 or more rows and have them not affect each other?

Any thoughts/help is welcome

```
    <form id="add_time">

    <template name="row">
    <ul>
        {{> clientsDD}}
        {{> projectsDD}}
        {{> hoursAndTasks}}
    </ul>
    </template> 

    <p><a href="#" id="newRow">Add another row</a>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_hours" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

    Template.clientsDD.clients = function() {

       return Clients.find({});

    }

    Template.projectsDD.projects = function(event) {

        return Projects.find({"client.clientId" : Session.get("clientSelected")});

    }



Template.addHours.events({


'change select[name="clientsDD"]' : function(event){

    newClient = $(event.target).val();
    Session.set("clientSelected", newClient);


},

'change select[name="projectsDD"]' : function(event){

    newProject = $(event.target).val();
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in my mind this can be done. As Meteor doesn't require page reloads to update your content. There is nothing to stop you have the row save on completion and then just having a loop which populates the page. Your form becomes something like this:

```
<form id="add_time">

{{#each rows}}
    {{> row}}
{{/each}}
{{> row}}

<input type="submit" id="submit_hours" value="Save and Add Another"/>
<input type="button" id="submit_and_exit" value="Save and Exit"/>

</form>

<template name="row">
<ul>
    {{> clientsDD _id}}
    {{> projectsDD _id}}
    {{> hoursAndTasks _id}}
</ul>
</template>
```

This would loop through a `rows` helper which contains your hours data displaying it for editing along with providing a new empty row. This would automatically update on save with no need for any DOM manipulation.

The other option is to duplicate the fields. I'm not aware of a method that allows you to duplicate a template but there's no reason why jQuery clone type function wouldn't work however you'd need to make sure that on saving they are saved separately. `clientsDD[]` as the input names should be okay as long as you give each group of fields a unique id.

I would personally use the first method thou as IMHO this is the way Meteor is designed to work so you don't have the need to manipulate the DOM as it will seamlessly update with the data store.